# If not <> NULL then "xxxField" equals '1'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a feeling this is a fairly simple one. I need to edit a line in the `SELECT` statement that looks to see if there is a value of `NULL` in a field. If there is a `NULL` value, I need the new column (not named) to display a '0' for that row. Where the row has data I need to display '1' in that row. Is there a way to do this without greatly modifying the logic I have? (Using SQL Server Management Studio)

Here's the code:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT t.Name,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.DischargeDateTime, 120) AS DischargeDate,
    t.PatientPortalEnabled,
    t.Allergy,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.AllergyUpdateTime, 120) AS AllergyUpdate,
    /*This is where I would like to put the logic if possible*/ <> NULL,
    t.ElapseTimeForAllergyUpdateInMinutes,
    t.OldValue,
    t.NewValue,
    t.ElapseTimeForAllergyUpdateInHours,
    t.DischargeDateTime
```

Comment: What if the field contains 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CASE WHEN MyField IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Here it is in your code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Name,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.DischargeDateTime, 120) AS DischargeDate,
t.PatientPortalEnabled,
t.Allergy,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.AllergyUpdateTime, 120) AS AllergyUpdate,
CASE WHEN t.MyField IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
t.ElapseTimeForAllergyUpdateInMinutes,
t.OldValue,
t.NewValue,
t.ElapseTimeForAllergyUpdateInHours,
t.DischargeDateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a [CASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Name,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.DischargeDateTime, 120) AS DischargeDate,
t.PatientPortalEnabled,
t.Allergy,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.AllergyUpdateTime, 120) AS AllergyUpdate,
/*This is where I would like to put the logic if possible*/
CASE
    WHEN t.MyField IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END AS MyNewField,
t.ElapseTimeForAllergyUpdateInMinutes,
t.OldValue,
t.NewValue,
t.ElapseTimeForAllergyUpdateInHours,
t.DischargeDateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Using XOR bitwise operator:

```
declare @x int = null
select isnull((@x ^ @x),-1)+1
```